# How to get the string buffer and use GETTEXTEX to translate the buffer to ANSI when receiving EM_GETTEXTEX in hooking SetWindowsHookEx WH_CALLWNDPROC

Tags: c++

The below is part of the callback function. as per this http://computer-programming-forum.com/81-vc/6dab353ca40b7def.htm . I trying to catch the URL from outlook when user trying to open hyperlink in outlook

```
if (nCode < 0)
    CallNextHookEx(hkb, nCode, wParam, lParam);

CWPSTRUCT* pwsStruct = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;

    if (pwsStruct->message == EM_GETTEXTEX)
    {
        writetofile("EM_GETTEXTEX:", f1);
        getTextEx = (GETTEXTEX*)pwsStruct->wParam;

        streamcb << (DWORD) getTextEx->cb;
        args = streamcb.str();
        writetofile(args, f1);

        streamcb << (UINT)getTextEx->codepage;
        args = streamcb.str();
        writetofile(args, f1);

        switch (getTextEx->flags)
        {
            case GT_DEFAULT:
                writetofile("GT_DEFAULT", 11, f1);
                break;
            case GT_NOHIDDENTEXT:
                writetofile("GT_NOHIDDENTEXT", 16, f1);
                break;
            case GT_RAWTEXT:
                writetofile("GT_RAWTEXT", 11, f1);
                break;
            case GT_SELECTION:
                writetofile("GT_SELECTION", 13, f1);
                break;
            case GT_USECRLF:
                writetofile("GT_USECRLF", 11, f1);
                break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        ***streamcb << (LPSTR)pwsStruct->lParam; 
        args = streamcb.str();
        fwrite(args.c_str(), 128, 1, f1);***
    }
```

Comment: So the question is: How to you take a `WCHAR*` buffer and convert it to a `char*` buffer? Look up [wcstombs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcstombs-s-wcstombs-s-l).

Comment: as per the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-gettextex from Microsoft we need to use WideCharToMultiByte. actually I am not expert with C++

Comment: On Windows, `wcstombs` simply uses `WideCharToMultiByte` under the covers. You can use either.

Comment: Thanks Andy. it is work fine.

Comment: Andy, I am trying to get the URL from hyper link in outlook when user open the hyperlink using SetwindowsHookEX with WH_CALLWNDPROCRET OR WH_CALLWNDPROC but I am not able aby idea which message is maybe has the value.